# Unable to hide loading image in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hi i am new to jquery mobile. I am trying to built mobile page using jquery mobile with master page and content page everything works fine except loading image displaying in page. I used   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); but no use. [image: Please] anybody guide me

The loading bar appearing even page load complete.

Comment: The Page Loading Widget

The page loading dialog was previously configured globally with three settings $.mobile.loadingMessage, $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible, and $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme which are now deprecated. In addition to the methods for showing and hiding, $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg and $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg **are also deprecated**.  

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/unable-to-hide-image-on-load-while-navigating   and   http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html

Comment: In the meantime, you are invited to read http://stackoverflow.com/help so you can get hints on 'how to'  formulate a decent question with a context, a 'live' example of what you have so far and all material needed to understand your situation.

Comment: @MilchePatern Sure. i will read it. thanks for your comment.

Comment: If the loading spinner doesn't hide, then you have a code problem. anyway, you can easily hide it `$('.ui-loader').hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` use `$.mobile.loading("hide");`.
Older versions of JQM used `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();`. Around 1.2 and above JQM uses `$.mobile.loading();` method.

Comment: i tried $.mobile.loading("hide"); with mobileinit but it does not work. here is my code

 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
           $.mobile.loading("hide");
       }); 
 </script>

After the page loads complete still the loading continuous to run.

Comment: Adding it to init does not help. It's not a global option. For gloabl otions see: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html

Comment: i am using JQM 1.3 but $.mobile.loading("hide"); not working. i am developing site using master page.. will it creatin problem.

Comment: You can call `$.mobile.loading("hide")` before `$.mobile.changePage()` method.

Comment: its not working. still the loading image displaying even after the page completly loads.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37339/discussion-between-ryder-and-kadaj)